# Extract values by matching points in ImageCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, extract

I am trying to extract pixel values by points and convert to a table in Google Earth Engine. I'd like to extract pixel values by lat,lon points I upload from a csv for each S2 image with a matching date. Before using the entire csv (3000+ points), I created two random points and am following the code in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742742/extract-pixel-values-by-points-and-convert-to-a-table-in-google-earth-engine?newreg=08192ec10d3c4cecbad6756f57de1158) to extract points. However, the table it output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoGIh.png). I'm not sure why only MSK_CLDPRB, MSK_SNWPRB, QA10, QA20, and QA60 are showing. I'd like all bands to be present. Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

```
// random points to create a FeatureCollection
var p1 = ee.Geometry.Point([-76.353, 39.094])
var p2 = ee.Geometry.Point([-76.133, 38.03])
var pts = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List([ee.Feature(p1),ee.Feature(p2)]))
print(pts)

// Cloud Mask function
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  //apply scaling factor and add prevent loss of timestamp
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
    .copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
}

// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.  
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
           //.filterDate('2017-03-28', '2020-05-20')
           .filterDate('2020-05-01', '2020-05-20')
           .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(-77, 39))
           .map(maskS2clouds);

print(S2);

// Empty Collection to fill
var ft = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List([]))

var fill = function(img, ini) {
  // type cast
  var inift = ee.FeatureCollection(ini)

  // gets the values for the points in the current img
  var ft2 = img.reduceRegions(pts, ee.Reducer.first(),30)

  // gets the date of the img
  var date = img.date().format()

  // writes the date in each feature
  var ft3 = ft2.map(function(f){return f.set("date", date)})

  // merges the FeatureCollections
  return inift.merge(ft3)
}

// Iterates over the ImageCollection
var newft = ee.FeatureCollection(S2.iterate(fill, ft))
print(newft)

// Export
Export.table.toDrive(newft,"extract_test");
```

[Link to code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/eec357fc34cc7c2cf668193e5b734b3b?asset=users%2Fawindle110%2F6class_Baywide)

Comment: For sampling raster, GEE has `sampleRegions` method to extract pixel values for each band of an image. This will sure extract all bands.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you, that worked for one image but now I am wondering how to use that to extract band values in images from coordinates with matching dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` method over your `S2` image collection to extract pixel values. Example code is below:

```
var newft = ee.FeatureCollection(S2.map(function (img) {
  return img.sampleRegions({collection: pts, scale: 30, geometries: true})
})).flatten()
```

Since each `sampleRegions` returns a feature collection, the outcome of the `map` function would be a collection of feature collection. Therefore, `flatten` is used to convert it to a 1-D feature collection.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I have accomplished this with GEE python api.

```
def rasterExtraction(image):
    feature = image.sampleRegions(
        collection = ee_fc, # feature collection here
        scale = 10 # Cell size of raster
    )
    return feature

results = Sentinel_data.filterBounds(ee_fc).select('NDVI', 'EVI').map(addDate).map(rasterExtraction).flatten()
```

For details, follow the link: https://kaflekrishna.com.np/blog-detail/extraction-raster-values-point-samples-google-earth-engine-gee/